# Python: How to refer to a digit in a string by its index?

Tags: python, string, indexing, digit

I feel like this is a simple question, but it keeps escaping me...

If I had a string, say, "1010101", how would I refer to the first digit in the string by its index?

Answer (score 5):

You can get the first element of *any* sequence with `[0]`. Since a string is a sequence of characters, you're looking for `s[0]`:

```
>>> s = "1010101"
>>> s[0]
'1'
```

For a detailed explanation, refer to the [Python tutorial on strings](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Comment: But in numbers as strings the "first digit" is actually on the right side.

Comment: @Keith In which case you'd use `[-1]`.

Comment: @Keith: Use `s[-1]` to get the first digit by your definition, `s[-2]` to get the second, etc.

Comment: Thanks, both of you, also, how would i refer to the index of that digit? Like, say I wanted to compare the index of a digit in the string to the index of another item in another string, how would i refer to the index of item in the string?

Comment: No, that's the least-significant digit. *First* is not formally defined, but in a big-endian notation, the first digit is the most significant.

Comment: @HershS. If this or Keith's, or any other answer solves your problem, feel free to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Thanks!

Comment: @phihag Yes, exactly. I'm guessing what the OP really meant was the first significant digit. Since getting the first element (zero) is pretty obvious.

Comment: @Keith Sorry, I have no idea what the *first* significant digit is, and I can't find any definition of it. I only of the [LSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_byte)/[MSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_byte)

Comment: @phihag Sorry, firt number place. In our system that is the rightmost character (digit) in a integer string. So we count digits from right to left. We call this the "Arabic number system" since we got it from the Arabs and they read right to left. Therefore, the "first digit" would be the rightmost in a string. If you get the leftmost then it has not meaning without also knowing the length of the string (to get it's "place").

Answer (score 1):

Negative indexes count from the right side.

```
digit = mystring[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, a sting is something called, `subscriptable`. That means that you can access the different parts using square brackets, just like you can with a list.

- If you want to get the first character of the string, then you can simply use `my_string[0]`.
- If you need to get the last (character) in a string (the final `1` in the string you provided), then use `my_string[-1]`.
- If you originally have an `int` (or a `long`) and you are looking for the last digit, you are best off using `%` (modulous) (`10101 % 10 => 1`).
- If you have a float, on the other hand, you are best of `str(my_float)[-1]`